# Bonemeal doesn't work with dispensers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So when I try using bonemeal to make crops grow faster it just breaks the crop instantly instead of actually growing. It does work in Single player but is there anyway to make it work in multiplayer because it might be a plugin?

Comment: What crop is it? Is it from a mod? I know enderlily seeds from ExtraUtilities  does that

Comment: Might be an insufficient light level.

Comment: I would say the light level, or perhaps the fact that it's a server - it never works too well with the latency from playing online.